# How to set the period of a periodic task in Firebase JobDispatcher?

Tags: android, android-service, android-background, periodic-task, firebase-job-dispatcher

I've read every available official docs (which is surprisingly not a lot) and all I could get for periodic tasks is this code

```
            .setRecurring(true)
            // start between 0 and 60 seconds from now
            .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 60))
```

I know that `.setRecurring`makes the job periodic and that the `trigger` makes it start in a 60 seconds interval but what about the second time it's executed ? does this mean that the 2nd time would be also executed 60 seconds starting from the 1st one ?

This can't be true because even taking in consideration the optimisation in the background activities and how services run a little later than they're supposed to, programming 60 seconds period while the job runs about 5/10/20 minutes later is too much of a difference. The official docs say that the difference is seconds and maybe a few minutes not over 20 mins.

**Basically, my question is does this          `.setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 60))` really mean that the period is 60 seconds or am I gettin this wrong ?**

Answer (score 6):

When it is non periodic.

```
.setRecurring(false)
.setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(x, y))
```

This code will run our job between the time **x** seconds from the job was scheduled and **y** seconds from the job was scheduled.

**x** is know as **windowStart**, which is  the earliest time (in seconds) the job should be considered eligible to run. Calculated from when the job was scheduled (for new jobs)

**y** is know as **windowEnd**, The latest time (in seconds) the job should be run in an ideal world. Calculated in the same way as **windowStart**.

When it is periodic

```
.setRecurring(true)            
.setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(x, y))
```

This code will run our job between the time **x** seconds from the job was scheduled and **y** seconds from the job was scheduled.Since this is periodic the next execution will be scheduled **x** seconds after the job is finished.

May refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42111723/5129938) answer also.

Answer (score 0):

it will be clearer if you look at the source of Trigger class [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/blob/master/jobdispatcher/src/main/java/com/firebase/jobdispatcher/Trigger.java)

it states:

```js
    /**
     * Creates a new ExecutionWindow based on the provided time interval.
     *
     * @param windowStart The earliest time (in seconds) the job should be
     *                    considered eligible to run. Calculated from when the
     *                    job was scheduled (for new jobs) or last run (for
     *                    recurring jobs).
     * @param windowEnd   The latest time (in seconds) the job should be run in
     *                    an ideal world. Calculated in the same way as
     *                    {@code windowStart}.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the provided parameters are too
     *                                  restrictive.
     */
    public static JobTrigger.ExecutionWindowTrigger executionWindow(int windowStart, int windowEnd) {
        if (windowStart < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Window start can't be less than 0");
        } else if (windowEnd < windowStart) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Window end can't be less than window start");
        }

        return new JobTrigger.ExecutionWindowTrigger(windowStart, windowEnd);
    }
```

or just Ctrl+Click the `Trigger` then Android Studio will bring you to its source. so if you write: `.setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 60))` then it will be run every seconds