# Best way for android background countdown timer

Tags: android, countdowntimer, background-service

I have data stored in a database using Firebase and I want it to be stored there for x amount of time, let's say 24 hours, and then removed. Is it better to use a background service countdown timer or to store the time in the database and check time difference until it is 24 hours? What would be the optimal way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service countdown is the battery drainer and it is not context aware of battery level, there is no use in syncing data on device which is about to die, I would prefer Jobscheduler which will intelligently act as per various environment criteria met like charging/idle.

Use [Firebase JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android#user-content-firebase-jobdispatcher-)

In addition to this, there are several other facilities available to help your app schedule work. These include:

- AlarmManager
- [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html)
- [SyncAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.html)

**Caution:** exponential backoff is enabled on job dispactchers/schedulers

For 24-hour logic check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42111723/2700586)